# Como apuntar el dominio a mi hosting personal

Tags: apache, hosting, servidor, dominio

recientemente he comprado un dominio en 1&1 y quisiera que el dominio apunte a mi servidor linux que tengo en mi ordenador.

La dirección de puertos de mi router esta así, es correcta ?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El DNS de mi dominio lo tengo así configurado, la ip 47.63.140.60 es la mía.
[image: ffrfr]

Que mas debería de configurar para que funcione mi pagina web?La pagina web esta en el servidor linux y usa bind y apache, tengo que crear allí un dominio local?o no es necesario?

Comment: eso va a ser imposible de configura, primero: un dominio deber apunta a una IP publica Y si desea apunta a su computador personal que tiene una IP privada, en ese caso deber habla con su proveedor de internet si le ofrecer una ip publica, ya que solo el route es visible desde afuera, la privada es la que identifica a cada uno de los dispositivos conectados a nuestra red, por lo tanto, cada una de las direcciones IP que el router asigna a nuestro ordenador, móvil, tablet o cualquier otro dispositivo que se esté conectado a él.

Comment: Todos tenemos una ip publica, pero es dinámica. Lo que podrías es hablar con tu proveedor y contratar una ip publica estática, los costos no son muy altos. Y ya con la ip publica estática puedes montar tu server.